# NodeJS returns "undefined" when get a folder name

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am trying to get a specified folder name which has a varied version number suffix with NodeJS like this:

```
this.getUeeFolderName = function(path)
{
var fileLists = fs.readdirSync(path);
for(var i =0 , l = fileLists.length; i < l ; i++)
    {
        fileName = fileLists[i];
        state = fs.statSync(path+"/"+fileName);
        if(state.isDirectory())
            {
                if(fileName.indexOf('appmw-uee-frontend-') >= 0)
                    {
                        return fileName;
                    }
            }
    }

};
```

But it sometimes returns "undefined", sometimes returns expected string.

Note:This folder cannot be empty since it is a tomcat working directory, my project is always running in tomcat.

Comment: is your folder sometimes empty ? You need to return a default string if your folder does not have any files

Comment: what happens if you `console.log(fileLists[i])`

Comment: I think your code is fine. Maybe you run from other working directories each time? Try to use absolute path then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `path` is an empty directory, `fs.readdirSync(path)` will return an empty array (`[]`).

In that case, the `for` loop will run zero times. A function that runs that `for` loop as its last step will return `undefined` in that case. (The `return` statement inside the `for` loop is never executed in that case.)

So this could be happening when `path` is an empty directory.

Another possibility, though, is that the `if` condition is never satisfied. This will also cause the `return` statement to be skipped. So, if there is no directory within `path` that contains `appmw-uee-frontend-` as part of the name, then the function will also return `undefined`.

One last possibility: There is a race condition in the code. The directory may exist when `fs.readdirSync()` is run, but then may be removed or renamed (by another process) before `fs.statSync()` is called on it. In that case, it is not returned, and you get `undefined`. Especially if there are a large number of entries to loop through, that may be what's going on too (although I'd recommend confirming the other possibilities aren't what's happening first).

Comment: This path is a tomcat working directory, it cannot be empty since my project is always running in tomcat.

Comment: @BobBai I've updated my answer to include another possibility.

Comment: This may happen because this is a CI environment, but it's hard to monitor and debug.

Comment: @BobBai There is at least one other possibility. There is a race condition in the code. The directory may exist when `fs.readdirSync()` is run, but then may be removed or renamed before `fs.statSync()` is called on it and so it is not returned, and you get `undefined` that way. So (especially if there are a large number of entries to loop through) that may be what's going on too. (I'll update the answer to reflect this.)

Comment: How is `this.getUeeFolderName` called? Does it get any path as an argument where `__dirname` or similar global is used? Maybe you are using absolute paths but they consist of such variables, making it context sensitive and by this pointing to non-existent content.

Comment: @dth I call this function as below:`var carFolder = "D:/CI/OpenAS_Tomcat7/webapps/ueecomposer.cars/";
    var carFolderName = Pages.site.getUeeFolderName(carFolder);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach()` method rather using a for loop. It will solve your issue:

Snippet:

```
 this.getUeeFolderName = function(path)
   {
    var fileLists = fs.readdirSync(path);

   fileLists.forEach(fileName,i)
    {
     state = fs.statSync(path+"/"+fileName);
     if(state.isDirectory())
        {
            if(fileName.indexOf('appmw-uee-frontend-') >= 0)
                {
                    return fileName;
                }
        }
    }
 };
```

Comment: The `for` loop is properly formed and doesn't appear to be the issue.